# is it possible to pull from private repo when using crictl

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

when I use crictl `crictl version 1.20.0-24-g53ad8bb7` to pull some private repo:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# crictl pull registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00
FATA[0000] pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00": failed to resolve reference "registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I have tried to pull with user name and password like this:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# crictl pull --creds jiangquan:$mydepo1789 registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00
FATA[0000] pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00": failed to resolve reference "registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:a56aeb198d9d4dc5548aa6d7ce6ede8890035e00": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I also tried to add config in `/etc/containerd/config.toml` like this and restart the containerd:

```
[plugin."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com".auth]
  username = "jiangquan"
  password = "$mydepo1789"
  auth = ""
  identitytoken = ""
```

both could not work. this is the document I am follow https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/registry.md#configure-registry-tls-communication. what should I do to pull private image using crictl?